# How to compile MATLAB code to be used with QT C++

Tags: c++, qt, matlab, mixed-code

I have 2 sets of code:

- MATLAB code, and
- QT C++ code.

I have tried to compile the MATLAB code to a C++ library using the `mcc` command with the msvc2008 compiler. For my QT C++ code, I'm using mingw to compile. However, when I try to add in the MATLAB converted C++ code there seems to be a lot of problems.

Is it possible to mix these two types of code together? Does anyone have any experiences using a combination of these languages?

! have tried to use Octave but I would rather not recode my MATLAB code. I am trying to look for an alternative to run MATLAB code directly.

NB: I need to use mingw in QT as it is requirement and for matlab mcc command, I only have the choice to use msvc compiler. It would be best if I could make the program as a standalone for portability. The reason why I need to use MATLAB code is because there are some nice matrix math manipulation functions I need and also because it would be easier for me to do research using MATLAB.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/index.html?s_cid=global_nav

Answer (score 4):

When you compile matlab code using `mcc` (by default or when using the `-m option`), you get an executable. So from your C++ file, you can call the matlab executable with the C/C++ command `exec`.

If you use the `-l option` (using `mcc`), you get a shared library, and header.
For instance if you type (in matlab):

```
mcc -l test.m -W cpplib:test.h
```

This should produce a shared library `test.lib` or `test.so`, and a header `test.h`

In `test.h` you should have line similar to that:

bool MW_CALL_CONV mlxTest(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, mxArray *prhs[]);

You can call your matlab function using that.

In addition you have to add both shared libraries and headers in you msvc project.

Comment: actually, the problem that i have is that if i were to use mcc command to compile to C, i would need to create a msvc project since it needs some functionality from msvc compiler. i'm actually looking for an answer which could be used with mingw compiler with my QT though.

Comment: It's still possible to do it with mingw and QT, there is no problem.

Comment: i am meeting with compilation error in QT mingw.
[code]
example: Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\extern\include\mclmcr.h:314: error: 'mxInt64' has not been declared
[/code]
seems like it is some problem that have got to do with mingw or extern by matlab is built for msvc in mind only.

Comment: you have to include mex.h and the corresponding libraries

Comment: i have tried your "mcc -l test.m -W cpplib:test.h", and added mex.h and still received the mxInt64 error. and anyway, i don't think mex.h is needed as i have compile it to dynamic library file not mex file

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the mxInt64 and mxUint64 by adding more typedefs to make the code recognize those as signed and unsigned integers 64 bytes long.